# Convert vector of dynamic Eigen vectors to bytes

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a function to convert static `Eigen` vectors to a vector of bytes:

```
template<typename T, int N>
static std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1>> const & vectors)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
    uint8_t const * rawData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const *>(vectors.data());
    bytes.insert(bytes.end(), rawData, rawData + vectors.size() * N * sizeof(T));
    return bytes
}
```

This was sufficient until dynamic `Eigen` vectors showed up (i.e. `Eigen::VectorXf`), which have the `N` set to `-1`. So I came up with this:

```
template<typename T>
static std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>> const & vectors)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
    uint8_t const * rawData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const *>(vectors.data());
    bytes.insert(bytes.end(), rawData, rawData + vectors.size() * sizeof(vectors[0]));
    return bytes
}
```

This however results in a vector that is four times as big as expected, so I guess that dynamic vectors cannot not be trivially converted to bytes as a static vector. I can fix the size problem like this:

```
template<typename T>
static std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>> const & vectors)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
    uint8_t const * rawData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const *>(vectors.data());
    bytes.insert(bytes.end(), rawData, rawData + vectors.size() *  vectors[0].size() * sizeof(T));
    return bytes
}
```

This results in a vector of the correct length filled with values, but these values are not correct. How can I convert a vector of dynamic `Eigen` vectors to a vector of bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there is one very obvious solution to this:

```
template<typename T>
static std::vector<uint8_t> createBuffer(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>> const & vectors)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> & bytes = buffer.bytes;
    bytes.reserve(vectors.size() * vectors[0].size() * sizeof(T));

    for (auto const & vector : vectors)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
        {
            uint8_t const * rawData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const *>(&vector(0));
            bytes.insert(bytes.end(), rawData, rawData + sizeof(T));
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: The `reserve` will be sub-optimal if the entries of `vectors` have different sizes. And of course, the content of `bytes` won't be sufficient to recreate the same `vectors` back from it (you need additional information about individual sizes).

Comment: @chtz You are correct! This only works for my case, since all Eigen vectors have the same size. I don't think there is a general solution to this problem since you would have to save extra data about the length of each Eigen vector